# Updating CoreFoundation PriorityQueue implementation to take advantage of ARC for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, priority-queue, core-foundation

I found [an implementation of a priority queue](http://three20.pypt.lt/cocoa-objective-c-priority-queue) that primarily uses `CFBinaryHeap` to work.

I'm currently using the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag to skip the usage of ARC while compiling these files. I attempted to update this code to take advantage of ARC, though I've run into a few snags of understanding.

Is there anyone here who has updated code similar to this for use with ARC?

How do you handle things like `free()`, and `CFRelease()`? Can we just get rid of them?

What do you do with the `retain` and `release` methods you create for `CFBinaryHeapCallBacks`?

Do you use `__bride` or `__bridge_transfer` to reference the `const void *` into Objective-C objects? Likewise should you use `(__bridge_retained void *)` or `obj_unretainedPointer()` to do the reverse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ARC basically is a compiler technology that automatically inserts calls to `-retain`, `-release`, and `-autorelease` as needed. It does not remove the need for retains and releases, it just makes them automatic (in the process, optimizing out many that are not required, and playing other tricks to make various common patterns much more efficient than if you did it by hand).

ARC knows nothing about Core Foundation, nor about `void*` objects, `malloc`, `free`, or anything other than ObjC memory management.

This means that as long as you use Core Foundation objects, you should continue to use `CFRelease`. And if you `malloc` memory, you should continue to `free` it.

But.... what if you want to take memory that was created by Core Foundation and transfer it to Cocoa via a toll-free bridge? That's where `__bridge*` comes in. One of the best sources of information is the [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts) themselves. A great blog article is [Everything you need to know about ARC](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/). It includes many useful links to the definitive information.

But here's the short answer (from [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html))

```
NSString   *c = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)my_cfref; // -1 on the CFRef
CFStringRef d = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)my_id;  // returned CFRef is +1
```

Using `__bridge_transfer` logically moves a CF object into Cocoa. Using `__bridge_retained` logically moves a Cocoa object into CF. You use these when you are really transferring ownership of the object. In the above example, you generally shouldn't continue using the `my_` variables in my opinion. These are particularly useful in cases where you are returning the result out of the function. These should be used for their logical ownership functionality only. Don't use them as a way to "fake" a manual call to `retain` or `release`.

If you just want to have a temporary "bridged" pointer to the object so you can use it in CF or Cocoa without transferring it, then use `__bridge`. That's a no-op that says "don't do any memory management, just let me pretend for the moment that it's the other kind of object." If you do a lot of toll-free bridging, you'll wind up using `__bridge` quite a lot (making it seem like a small toll.... :D)

Comment: You may also use `(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(my_cfref)` instead of `(__bridge_transfer NSString *)my_cfref`, or `(CFStringRef)CFBridgingRetain(my_id)` instead of `(__bridge_retained CFStringRef)my_id`.

Comment: @KevinBallard Agreed. The two are identical, and which you use is a matter of taste.

Comment: Just an update for those reading later: after having developed with ARC for several months, I have found `CFBridgingRelease()` and `CFBridgingRetain()` much clearer and easier to understand than `__bridge_transfer` and `__bridge_retained`. The function form is now my recommended approach.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure objective-c implementation of PriorityQueue, that supports ARC:
https://github.com/jessedc/JCPriorityQueue/tree/experimental/heap-queue

Answer (score 1):

Is simple to implement non ARC lib into XCode project. Just open "Build Phases"(menu when click on your project target) -> "Compile Sources" and to files, which are not using ARC add by double click flag "-fno-objc-arc" and your're done. So simple :)